# Wordpress custom post query with pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I know this is a common issue and there are many solutions out there. Fow showing custom post with WP query , I use a a snippet like this

```
<?php 
  $temp = $wp_query; 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
  $wp_query->query('showposts=6&post_type=news'.'&paged='.$paged); 

  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>

  <!-- LOOP: Usual Post Template Stuff Here-->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<nav>
    <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
</nav>

<?php 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
?>
```

It works fine . But this doesn't work when I use it in admin panel . I have tried many other solutions but none of them work in `Wp admin` panel . Is there any way so that I can display custom post with pagination in admin panel .